# How to implement multiple item selection?

Tags: javascript, language-agnostic, multipleselection

I'm working on a drawing application where the user can create and delete shapes and select them with the mouse to drag them. Should selected shapes be referenced in a "selection" array or should they each have an isSelected property? Is there any advantage to one method over the other? Here's what I noticed so far (I will update it with whatever people find). My main concerns are programming simplicity and performance. This question is language independent for the most part, but the app is in javascript and rendering is done on an html5 canvas.

**Checking for selection state**

While we know instantaneously if an item is selected through the boolean property, the array-based solution requires looping through the array to search for the item's reference. This verification is quite common considering the cursor should change to a "dragging" icon when the mouse hovers a selected shape or a "pointing hand" icon when it hovers over a non-selected item.

**Deselecting items**

Selecting and deselecting specific items is instantaneous with the boolean property. With the array-selection, however, we must first loop through the selection to see if the item is there before adding or removing it from the selection. This makes "toggle selection" and "add to selection" options much slower. However, the most common action in such a drawing program is to clear the selection before selecting specific elements. With the array method, clearing the selection is as simple as replacing the array, while the boolean method requires setting the isSelected property to false on all items.

**Deleting items**

It is worth mentioning that an item must be removed from the selection array before it gets deleted. This detail doesn't show up in the isSelected approach.

**Calling on all selected items**

Actions which apply to all selected items require minimal code with an array as we only have to loop through the selection and call the method on each element. If the selection is small compared to the total amount of items, having to loop only through the selection can be a considerable time gain. With a boolean property, the time required to call an action on all selected items depends on the total amount of items instead of the selection's size.

**Drawing time**

Selected items commonly have colored borders that can be seen through other elements. It means that selection borders must be drawn in front of all other elements. Given the number of items "n" and the number of selected items ("s")...

The array solution takes from `O(n)` to `2*O(n)` to render.
The boolean solution takes about `2*O(n)` to render.

While you might think that this justifies opting for the array method on its own, keep in mind that redrawing is only done after actions are triggered, not 60 times a second. Checking the pointed shape to know if it is selected or not is more common then drawing. The only features that might noticeably slow down are dragging, stretching and making rectangle selections. Since the application is used to represent real life items, people usually enter the size they want on their keyboard instead of actually dragging items.

**Encapsulation**

The encapsulation is stronger with a boolean property, as items know whether they are selected or not without having to look at an application-scope variable. That difference can mean a lot in strict-scope environments, but it isn't that big of a deal in javascript. I suppose one could think that it isn't the shapes' role to select themselves.

Comment: I suggest you look into MV* programming patterns, as they relate to JavaScript: Backbone.js, Angular.js, Ember.js and other frameworks help  with these types of issues.

http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/nanil/archive/2013/04/01/exploring-javascript-mv-frameworks-part-1-hello-backbonejs.aspx

Comment: @Diodeus I don't see how that can help me, considering it's a client only app without a database and the question I have is mostly UI-related. Besides, most of the application is done, I can't just add a framework to it.

Comment: MV* patterns do not need to communicate with a back-end in order to be used. Client side models, templates, view and events are still valid and useful in the type of application you are building. Yes, it's probably too late in the game for what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented the boolean isSelected property and as the application grew, I built more and more functions which applied to all elements. In each function, I had to put a for loop which would make sure to only alter selected items. I'll write some kind of pseudo-code to keep this solution language agnostic again.

```
for each item {
  if item is selected
    do stuff
}
```

Having the same loop everywhere annoyed me, it felt wrong. When you copy-paste code parts between functions, it's never a good sign. So I made a getSelection() function which returned an array of the selected elements. That seemed to solve the problem I had before by extracting the horrible loop.

```
function getSelection() {
  selection = new empty array

  for each item in selection {
    if item is selected
      add item to selection array
  }
  return selection
}

function doStuffOnSelection() {
  selection = getSelection()

  for each item in selection {
    do stuff
  }
}
```

But this only revealed something much worse. Manipulating arrays (constantly pushing items into an array, creating an array, etc) is much slower than just looking through them. This change slowed down the application so much that in Firefox, I couldn't even have 100 items at once while I used to be able to have 2000 without a frame drop. Such a slowdown all because I now create an array. That's because the getSelection function needs to be called on every frame of the program to draw a blue border on all selected elements!

When I posted this question, I wasn't sure if it was premature optimization, now I know it wasn't.

**The major downsides of keeping track of selected items with an array**
 - You need to look at all selected elements to determine if a specific element is selected and to change that state.
 - To remove selected elements from the array of all elements, you need array researching, which is especially slow when either array is big.

**The major downside of keeping track of selected items with a per-item boolean**
 - You need to look at all elements to know which elements are selected and to change that state.

So I've settled on a much better way to deal with all the negative sides: do both. I'll keep an array of selected items in the background, which gets updated when things are selected and deselected. This gets rid of all the bad sides of array-only selection, as I no longer need to search through any array to know if a specific element is selected (I can look at its boolean). And all functions which apply to selected items but do not select and deselect items (such as move, resize, draw) can just loop through the selection array. The best of both worlds!

Comment: Ok, it seems firefox is still slow with that solution. It must be due to the added functionality to rotate elements. The gain in performance isn't that noticable.